# How to put a string into a new column based on the information/condition from other column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame which shows like this:

```
type      office A    office B   office C    information      
A             0          0         1           number        
A             0          0         0           fatality        
A             0          0         0           frequency      
B             1          0         0           number          
B             0          1         0           fatality        
B             0          0         0           frequency 
C             0          0         0           number   
C             0          0         0           fatality  
C             0          0         0           frequency
```

I want to add new columns of number, fatality, frequency, and type which the value is from the office and information column. For example, if office C has a value which is more than 0 and the information column shows "number", then the value will fill in the new column "number". Meanwhile, the "type" column will shows C because the value is coming from office C. It will be left NaN if there is no any value between 3 office.

my desired results is like this:

```
type      office A    office B   office C    information     number   fatality     frequency     type    
A             0          0         1           number          1         0             0          C
A             0          0         0           fatality        0         0             0          NaN
A             0          0         0           frequency       0         0             0          NaN
B             1          0         0           number          1         0             0          A
B             0          1         0           fatality        0         1             0          B
B             0          0         0           frequency       0         0             0          NaN
C             0          0         0           number          0         0             0          NaN
C             0          0         0           fatality        0         0             0          NaN
C             0          0         0           frequency       0         0             0          NaN
```

I get so confused on how to develop the 4 new columns. Looking forward for anyhelp from here. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the expected output when more than one office column has a value over 0 but otherwise try this:

```
df:
    type      office A    office B   office C    information      
    A             0          0         1           number        
    A             0          0         0           fatality        
    A             0          0         0           frequency      
    B             1          0         0           number          
    B             0          1         0           fatality        
    B             0          0         0           frequency 
    C             0          0         0           number   
    C             0          0         0           fatality  
    C             0          0         0           frequency

for val in df.information.unique().tolist():
    df[val] = np.where(df.information==val, df.officeA+df.officeB+df.officeC, 0)

df['type_1'] = np.where(((df.number+df.fatality+df.frequency>0) &
                         (df.officeC>0)), 'C',
                         np.where(((df.number+df.fatality+df.frequency>0) &
                         (df.officeB>0)), 'B',
                        np.where(((df.number+df.fatality+df.frequency>0) &
                        (df.officeA>0)), 'A', np.nan)))
```

The above should give you the desired output. You can't have 2 columns with the same name unless you want to replace the first `type` column with the new one

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not a problem related to adding new columns I think.

You may need to JOIN one DataFrame with another DataFrame using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Answer (score 0):

For each value that matches 'office' or 'fatality' or 'frequency', you want to flag the columns. Also you want to know which column referred has a value of 1.

To do this, you can start by defining:

```
dfoffice = (df['office A'] == 1) | (df['office B'] == 1) | (df['office C'] == 1)
```

with this, you can define the 3 new columns as follows:

```
df.loc[((df['information']=='number') & (dfoffice)),'number'] = 1
df.loc[((df['information']=='fatality') & (dfoffice)),'fatality'] = 1
df.loc[((df['information']=='frequency') & (dfoffice)),'frequency'] = 1
```

Now that you have got the values, you need to set the last column. A dataframe cannot have the same column. So let's create `type_1`

```
df.loc[(df['office A'] == 1),'type_1'] = 'A'
df.loc[(df['office B'] == 1),'type_1'] = 'B'
df.loc[(df['office C'] == 1),'type_1'] = 'C'

#fill all na with zero
df = df.fillna(0)
```

If we put all this together, we will get the below dataframe.

```
  type  office A  office B  office C  ... number  fatality  frequency  type_1
0    A         0         0         1  ...    1.0       0.0        0.0       C
1    A         0         0         0  ...    0.0       0.0        0.0       0
2    A         0         0         0  ...    0.0       0.0        0.0       0
3    B         1         0         0  ...    1.0       0.0        0.0       A
4    B         0         1         0  ...    0.0       1.0        0.0       B
5    B         0         0         0  ...    0.0       0.0        0.0       0
6    C         0         0         0  ...    0.0       0.0        0.0       0
7    C         0         0         0  ...    0.0       0.0        0.0       0
8    C         0         0         0  ...    0.0       0.0        0.0       0
```

The full code is listed below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                   'office A':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'office B':[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                   'office C':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'information':['number','fatality','frequency']*3})
print (df)

dfoffice = (df['office A'] == 1) | (df['office B'] == 1) | (df['office C'] == 1)

df.loc[((df['information']=='number') & (dfoffice)),'number'] = 1
df.loc[((df['information']=='fatality') & (dfoffice)),'fatality'] = 1
df.loc[((df['information']=='frequency') & (dfoffice)),'frequency'] = 1

df.loc[(df['office A'] == 1),'type_1'] = 'A'
df.loc[(df['office B'] == 1),'type_1'] = 'B'
df.loc[(df['office C'] == 1),'type_1'] = 'C'
df = df.fillna(0)

print (df)
```